# Insert into a table using a view

Tags: sql

I have some data in a view which I want to insert into a table (same table schema) what's the easiest, cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (Col1, Col2,...)
Select Col1, Col2, ...
From dbo.MyView
```

Answer (score 12):

if you want to insert the entire column then you can do like

```
   insert into table_name
   select * from view_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into mytable(c1, c2, c3, ...)
select c1, c2, c3, ... from myview
```